# Minimal server configuration only to send logs via mail from scripts on Ubuntu

Tags: scripts, email

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 configured as Gateway and OpenVpn server. I have made a script that changes the VPN destination based on destination reach-ability. Now I want a simple command included on the script that send a notification on my email address on a local server every time a change was made.
ex..

> /bin/mail -s 'VPN on internet' abc.def@gh.eu

I saw on the forums that i can use `postfix` or `exim4`  but I don't want to install big software on this machine because this role as GW shouldn't fail.
I know that are scripts on php that send mails but I don't wont to include php neither. I'm interested on a solution the way that php works but as bash script :)

Answer (score 2):

You may use smtp client software intended to emulate mail/sendmail commands - it does not requite installation of local MTA/SMTP server. You may consider [**m**smtp](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=msmtp&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all) or [send**e**mail](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=sendemail&searchon=names).

Another option is to install full blown MTA/SMTP server configured to relay all locally submitted messages to mailbox on another host without listening on smtp port 25.
[I may add more details if you are interested]

Comment: Thanks for answering, are you sure that this softwares doesn't consume much resources and doesn't cause system fail on any circumstances? Because as I said the Gateway role is very crucial and I don't want to add a new point of failure. (sorry for my paranoia)

Comment: @emirjonb I use it msmtp but only sporadically.  I have not tested it in "heavy duty" situation.